# Recursive Alexa Response with DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

so I am basically trying to tell an interactive story with Alexa. However, I am not sure how to edit an intent response while being said by Alexa. This should happen in a way, that keeps it updating while Alexa tells the story.

In my scenario Alexa is only one daemon fetching strings from DynamoDB and while new story lines are being generated she is supposed to read and then tell them as soon as they're processed. It seems that Alexa needs completed Strings as a return value for its response.
Here an example:

**User:** Alexa, tell me a story.

**Alexa:** (checks DynamoDB table for a new sentence, if found) *says sentence*

**Other Device:** *updates story*

**Alexa:** (checks DynamoDB table for a new sentence, if found) *says sentence*

...

This would keep on going until the **other Device** puts an end-signifier to the DynamoDB table making Alexa respond a final *This is how the story ends* output.

Has anyone experience with such a model or an idea of how to solve it? If possible, I do not want a user to interact more then once for a story.

I am thinking of a solution where I would 'fake' user-intents by simply producing JSON Strings and pushing them through the speechlet requesting the new story-sentences hidden from the user... Anyhow, I am not sure wether this is even possible not to think of the messy solution this would be.. :D

Thanks in regard! :)

Answer (score 0):

The Alexa skills programming model was definitely not designed for this. As you can tell, there is no way to know, from a skill, when a text to speech utterance has finished, in order to be able to determine when to send the next.

Alexa also puts a restriction on how long a skill may take to respond, which I believe is somewhere in the 5-8 seconds range. So that is also a complication.

The only way I can think of accomplishing what you want to accomplish would be to use the GameEngine interface and use input handlers to call back into your skill after you send each TTS. The only catch is that you have to time the responses and hope no extra delays happen.

Today, the GameEngine interface requires you to declare support for Echo Buttons but that is just for metadata purposes. You can certainly use the GameEngine based skills without buttons.

Have a look at: [the GameEngine interface docs](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/gadget-skills/gameengine-interface-reference.html) and the **time out recognizer** to handle the time out from an input handler.

When you start your story, you’ll start an input handler. Send your TTS and sent a timeout in the input handler of however long you expect the TTS to take Alexa to say. Your skill will receive an event when the timeout expires and you can continue with the story.

You’ll probably want to experiment with setting the [playBehavior](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#outputspeech-object) to ENQUEUE.